# Use validate function to give error message in shiny

Tags: r, validation, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app which allows the user to select the variable of a data frame. There are two main controls: the variable selector using **varSelectInput** and a **checkboxInput** which is to identify if the variable should be log-transformed.
However, a character/factor might be chosen, in that case, a bar plot will be created.

However, in the case when a non-numerical variable is chosen and the log checkbox is checked, the user should be provided with an error message to indicate what went wrong. A minimal example is as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("testing for validate function"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            varSelectInput("variable",
                        "Select a variable",data = mtcars,multiple = FALSE),
            checkboxInput("log",label = "Log Transform?",value = FALSE)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("testPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    base_plot <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(!!input$variable))
    
    if (is.numeric(input$variable) & input$log==TRUE){
        p <- base_plot +geom_density()+
            scale_x_log10()
    } if (is.numeric(input$variable) & input$log==FALSE){
        p <- p+geom_density()
    } if (!is.numeric(input$variable) & input$log==FALSE){
        p <- base_plot+geom_bar(stat = "count")
    } else {"show the error message: you cannot log a non-numerical variable"}
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I looked it up and seems shiny has a **validate** function for this. However, the examples I got did not help me much to solve my problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

you can do utilize the `showNotification` for a notification handling. I've tidied up your code a bit, as you had spelling mistakes and didnt return anything amongst other things:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("testing for validate function"),
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            varSelectInput("variable",
                           "Select a variable",data = mtcars,multiple = FALSE),
            checkboxInput("log",label = "Log Transform?",value = FALSE)
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("testPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    myplot <- eventReactive(c(input$variable,input$log),{
        p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(!!input$variable))
        if(is.numeric(input$variable)){
            if(input$log){
                p <- p + geom_density()+ scale_x_log10()  
            }else{
                p <- p + geom_density()
            }
        }else{
            if(!input$log){
                p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "count")
            }else{
                showNotification("show the error message: you cannot log a non-numerical variable",type = "error", duration = 5)
                return()
            }
            
        }
        return(p)
    })
    
    output$testPlot <- renderPlot({
        myplot()
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]